# Check inputs of Stored Procedure in HANA

Tags: sql, hana

In stored procedure i would like to give a set of inputs, in which i also have some tables.

i could use if condition to handle empty scalar inputs but i dont know how to handle empty table or if the input is left empty.

I would like to have some thing like this

```
count = select count(*) from input_table;    
if :count = 0 or not given(~) --how to check if the input is not given?
then
tab = select * from table;
else 
tab = input_table;
end if;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Table t1
where exists(
select 1 from ChildTable t2
where t1.id = t2.parentid)
procedure
if exists(select 1 from table)
begin
 -- do stuff
end
```

Comment: hey Nisarg, Can you please explain me about the child table and its ids? I didnt really understood. thanks!